# Underlining section titles

Tags: sectioning, formatting

Is there a good way by specifying it in the preamble, to underline my section titles (not chapter titles), instead of having to do `\chapter{\underline{Section Title}}` for all chapter titles in the body?

I would like it as something like in this picture below:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: That is very bad typographical practice.

Comment: Oo, sorry, I totally switched chapter and section. I meant this one is for the section title, not chapter title. I need to make it that way because of the thesis formatting requirements.

Comment: Thnks, @JouleV, but I could not find how you can underline it and middle align it. I'm new to Latex actually.

Comment: @SamyamShrestha Look at the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick way using `sectsty`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\underline\normalfont\normalsize\centering}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{This is your section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that's sweet! Thanks! Similar to this (sectsty), what package can edit chapter titles?

Comment: `titlesec`, or you can even edit it manually by redefining `\chapter`.